# How to add "openerp-server.conf" file for odoo 10 in macOS

Tags: odoo

I receive the following error in console, and came to know this can be solved by adding openerp-server.conf file.

```
Jinn-MacBook-Air:odoo juasoft$ ./odoo-bin 
2017-01-15 15:05:16,937 4093 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 10.0
2017-01-15 15:05:16,937 4093 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /Users/juasoft/.odoorc
2017-01-15 15:05:16,937 4093 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/Users/juasoft/Library/Application Support/Odoo/addons/10.0', u'/Users/juasoft/git/odoo/odoo/addons', u'/Users/juasoft/git/odoo/addons']
2017-01-15 15:05:16,938 4093 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default
2017-01-15 15:05:16,971 4093 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2017-01-15 15:05:25,332 4093 INFO ? odoo.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2017-01-15 15:05:27,737 4093 INFO ? odoo.addons.report.models.report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports.
2017-01-15 15:05:29,162 4093 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files
2017-01-15 15:05:29,203 4093 INFO Odoo odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2017-01-15 15:05:29,239 4093 INFO Odoo odoo.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.04s, 0 queries
2017-01-15 15:05:29,291 4093 INFO Odoo odoo.modules.loading: loading 33 modules...
2017-01-15 15:05:29,511 4093 INFO Odoo odoo.modules.loading: 33 modules loaded in 0.22s, 0 queries
2017-01-15 15:05:29,924 4093 INFO Odoo odoo.modules.loading: Modules loaded.
2017-01-15 15:05:29,931 4093 INFO Odoo odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_http: Generating routing map
Python(4093,0x700002ea0000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fbbccf98df8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
Jinn-MacBook-Air:odoo juasoft$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a conf file executing this command

```
./odoo-bin -s -c openerp-server.conf
```